# AlmostIncreasingSequence(CodeSignal)

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, vector, sequence

I'm stuck in this challenge, and I thought of an algorithm which goes by:

```
bool almostIncreasingSequence(std::vector<int> Sequence)
{
    int counter = 0;
Label:
    std::vector<int>::iterator it = Sequence.begin();
    for (it; it != Sequence.end(); it++)
    {
        if (*(it) >= *(it + 1))
        {
            counter++;
            Sequence.erase(it);
            goto Label;
        }
    }
    return counter <= 1;
}
```

But I don't know why the output isn't right? What am I doing wrong in this code?

Here are the pictures of the challenge:

[image: Part1]
[image: Part2]

Comment: Does this work for `[1, 3, 1]` ? Answer for this should be `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Make the return condition <= 2 and add an extra if statement to check if you would go out of bounds or not:

```
bool almostIncreasingSequence(std::vector<int> Sequence)
{
    int counter{ 0 };
Label:
    std::vector<int>::iterator it = Sequence.begin();
    for (it; it != Sequence.end(); it++)
    {
        if ((it + 1 != Sequence.end())) //new if statement here
        if (*(it) >= *(it + 1))
        {
            ++counter;
            Sequence.erase(it);
            goto Label;
        }
    }
    return counter <= 2;
}
```

hope it works!

Comment: Does this work for `[1, 3, 1]` ? Answer for this should be `true`.

Comment: Also, why `<= 2`? Technically you can remove only 1 element.

Comment: The goto statement is preventing ++it from incrementing, at the same time (it) is being erased, going through the process sequentially and using the vector elements[1,2,3,1], we would see that counter would increment twice.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I cant comment I need at least  50 rep, anyways... it has to do with the Label and goto statements, I have never seen such implementation, however removing the label and goto would work and make counter <= 1:

```
bool almostIncreasingSequence(std::vector<int> Sequence)
{
    int counter{ 0 };

    std::vector<int>::iterator it = Sequence.begin();
    for (it; it != Sequence.end(); it++)
    {
        if ((it + 1 != Sequence.end()))
            if (*(it) >= *(it + 1))
            {
                ++counter;
            }
    }
    return counter <= 1;
}
```

Here is an explanation: the goto statement is preventing the for statement from incrementing (++it), in other words using the goto would skip the increment part. This is what I think, again best of luck.

Comment: I think the problem is with the iterator
what i've been thinking about was erasing the element that's ruining the sequence,and get back to the beginning of the sequence and add 1 to the counter,and repeat the same process for the whole sequence,and last thing is to check the condition,but the thing is the reference of that element will be invalidated after erasing so it will have a wrong output for sure,because the program will give random values
Hope I made it clear for you,what i've been trying to do

Answer (score -1):

```
bool almostIncreasingSequence(vector<int> v) {
int n = v.size();
int cnt =0;
if(n == 1 )
    return true;
    
for(int i=0; i<n-1; i++)
{
    if(v[i]>=v[i+1])
    {
        if((v[i]-v[i+2] == 0))
            cnt = 10;
        cnt++;
    }
    
}
if(cnt<=1)
    return true;
else 
    return false;
```

}

> was able to solve 17/19 test cases...let me know any further suggestions in this code.
> Error for this test case [40, 50, 60, 10, 20, 30] .

[problem statement link](https://app.codesignal.com/arcade/intro/level-2/2mxbGwLzvkTCKAJMG/drafts)

Comment: What's the point in posting a solution that fails in 2 out of 19 test cases?